# How to check if custom exception handler has been set?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I want to call `set_exception_handler()` only if no other exception handler has been register before, hence the default handler is in use.

I need that, because I want to log exceptions to file in production code, but I don't want to register exception handler when **PHPUnit** is running my code, because it need to catch all errors.

Comment: `set_exception_handler()` returns the name of the previously declared exception handler.

Comment: @Pekka: Pedantic note: it returns the callback, not the name.  So it could be a string, or an array, or an object (5.3+), etc...

Comment: @irc that's an important distinction, but the manual says: `Returns the name of the previously defined exception handler, or NULL on error` what you say would make more sense to me, though. Which is correct?  (Can't test right now...)

Comment: @Pekka: Quick test on 5.3.5 shows it does return the callback.  The docs appear to be off (but the method signature is correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (null !== set_exception_handler(yourHandler)) {
    restore_exception_handler();
}
```

[`set_exception_handler`](http://php.net/set_exception_handler) will return a non `null` value if an exception handler already is defined.